# Howto select and edit TabelCell in TableView with mouseclick on a MenuItem of ContextMenu - JavaFX

Tags: javafx, tableview, contextmenu, menuitem, tablecell

is there a possiblity to select & edit a `TableCell` within a `TableView` after one has mouse clicked or key pressed a certain `MenuItem` of a `ContextMenu`? The default `TextFieldTableCell` Implementation only supports pressing Enter key while a `TableRow` has focus or directly clicking into the respective cell to select & edit its content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If understand your question correctly, yes you can do this. Here's an example that lets you edit cells in the second column by using a context menu:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellEditEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class EditableTableMCVE extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        int numOfCols = 10;

        ObservableList<ObservableList<String>> tableData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        // Generate dummy data.
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

            for (int j = 0; j < numOfCols; j++)
                row.add("Row" + i + "Col" + j);

            tableData.add(row);
        }

        TableView<ObservableList<String>> table = new TableView<ObservableList<String>>();
        table.setEditable(true);

        // Add columns to the table.
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfCols; i++) {
            // We make all cells in column on index 1 editable.
            if (i == 1) {
                table.getColumns().add(addEditableColumn(i, "Column " + i));
            } else {
                table.getColumns().add(addColumn(i, "Column " + i));
            }
        }

        table.getItems().addAll(tableData);

        MenuItem editItem = new MenuItem("Edit");
        editItem.setOnAction(e -> {
            // We need to get the index of the selected row and the TableColumn
            // on the column index we want to edit.
            int selectedRowIndex = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
            table.edit(selectedRowIndex, table.getColumns().get(1));
        });
        ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu(editItem);
        table.setContextMenu(menu);

        Scene scene = new Scene(table);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * Returns a simple column.
     */
    private TableColumn<ObservableList<String>, String> addColumn(int index, String name) {
        TableColumn<ObservableList<String>, String> col = new TableColumn<ObservableList<String>, String>(name);
        col.setCellValueFactory(e -> new SimpleStringProperty(e.getValue().get(index)));
        return col;
    }

    /**
     * Returns an editable column.
     */
    private TableColumn<ObservableList<String>, String> addEditableColumn(int index, String name) {
        TableColumn<ObservableList<String>, String> col = new TableColumn<ObservableList<String>, String>(name);
        col.setCellValueFactory(e -> new SimpleStringProperty(e.getValue().get(index)));

        col.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        col.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<ObservableList<String>, String>>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(CellEditEvent<ObservableList<String>, String> t) {
                ((ObservableList<String>) t.getTableView().getItems().get(t.getTablePosition().getRow())).set(index,
                        t.getNewValue());
            }
        });
        return col;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Jonatan, yes you totally understood my issue. Thank you so much for your solution! Your line with `table.edit(selectedRowIndex, table.getColumns().get(1));` really helped me solving my case. Before that my code was `tbl.getSelectionModel().select(currentRow, colCardTotal);` which only works if a row was selected and having the Enter key pressed to make TableView go into edit mode.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by extending `TextFieldTableCell`.

**Example**

```
public class ContextTextFieldTableCell<S, T> extends TextFieldTableCell<S, T> {

    private void init() {
        MenuItem editItem = new MenuItem("edit");
        ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu(editItem);
        setContextMenu(contextMenu);
        setEditable(false);
        setOnContextMenuRequested(evt -> {
            editItem.setDisable(!(getTableColumn().isEditable() && getTableView().isEditable()));
        });
        editItem.setOnAction(evt -> {
            setEditable(true);
            getTableView().edit(getIndex(), getTableColumn());
        });
    }

    public ContextTextFieldTableCell() {
    }

    public ContextTextFieldTableCell(StringConverter<T> converter) {
        super(converter);
        init();
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelEdit() {
        super.cancelEdit();
        setEditable(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void commitEdit(T newValue) {
        super.commitEdit(newValue);
        setEditable(false);
    }

    public static <T> Callback<TableColumn<T, String>, TableCell<T, String>> cellFactory() {
        return cellFactory(new DefaultStringConverter());
    }

    public static <S, T> Callback<TableColumn<S, T>, TableCell<S, T>> cellFactory(final StringConverter<T> converter) {
        if (converter == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        return column -> new ContextTextFieldTableCell<>(converter);
    }

}
```

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    TableView<Item<String>> tableView = createTable();
    tableView.setEditable(true);

    TableColumn<Item<String>, String> editColumn = new TableColumn("value(editable)");
    editColumn.setCellFactory(ContextTextFieldTableCell.cellFactory());
    editColumn.setCellValueFactory(cd -> cd.getValue().valueProperty());
    tableView.getColumns().add(editColumn);

    Scene scene = new Scene(tableView);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Note that this removes the "standard" way of entering the edit mode. If you do not need this functionality, you can simply use a `cellFactory` to customize `TextFieldTableCell`:

```
public static <S, T> Callback<TableColumn<S, T>, TableCell<S, T>> cellFactory(final StringConverter<T> converter) {
    if (converter == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    return column -> {
        final TextFieldTableCell<S, T> cell = new TextFieldTableCell<>(converter);

        MenuItem editItem = new MenuItem("edit");
        ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu(editItem);
        cell.setContextMenu(contextMenu);

        cell.setOnContextMenuRequested(evt -> {
            editItem.setDisable(!(cell.isEditable() && cell.getTableColumn().isEditable() && cell.getTableView().isEditable()));
        });
        editItem.setOnAction(evt -> {
            cell.getTableView().edit(cell.getIndex(), cell.getTableColumn());
        });

        return cell;
    };
}
```

Comment: thanks Fabian. Your solution is quite nice in customizing the CellEditing process! I will try that in my next upcoming project.